# Probability that at least one of three other players has a card of the same suit as mine

Tags: probability

You and three other players each hold one card.  What is the probability that at least one of the three other players has a card with the same suit as the card in your hand.

This seems like it should be fairly easy to solve, but I went through a bit of computation to come up with 0.561, and I am not all confident of this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the probability that no one shares a card of the same suit (you have 1 card, so there are 51 left: 12 of the same suit, 39 of a different suit).

Subtract that probability from the total probability and what is left is the probability that at least one other person shares a card of the same suit.

Your estimate is very close.

Answer:

> $$1-\dfrac{\dbinom{39}{3}}{\dbinom{51}{3}} \approx 0.561$$

Comment: I used exactly the approach you describe, BUT, I laboriously separated out the cases, no one else has my suit, exactly one other has my suit, etc., coming up with the correct answer, but with a lot more work.